# Performance: Optimize laravel passport latency

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I'm using laravel passport as authentication mechanism on a Laravel project (exposing an API). The app was getting slow, I installed sentry profiler, and I found out most of the slowness came from Laravel Passport with some (IMHO) aberations:

- Login endpoint: **15 (!) db requests**

[image: Login]

- **~1s overhead** on all api endpoints that need authentication

[image]

- Finally, nearly all request stated there run in <1ms when ran on the mysql server (indexes are set right, table currently have ~100 users...), which is **600x faster** than what passport does (ok, there's a little network overhead but still...). Not sure why they take so long for passport ?

How can we improve this ?

EDIT: in particular, I see that first mysql request always takes much longer (600ms here). Could it be that laravel is loading plenty of things when first mysql request is done?

Comment: I am also using passport and experiencing it being quite slow. 
However I am not having the issues with queries as you have, mine is taking at max 7ms, however 1 whole second is spend afterwards waiting for passport.

Answer (score 0):

Try use :
laravel-passport-cache-token

https://github.com/overtrue/laravel-passport-cache-token

ref: https://github.com/laravel/passport/pull/1447#issue-902114838

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer with more details. A command with its documentation is a good start, but explaining how `laravel-passport-cache-token` would solve the problem at hand would be better.